# Нахождение цифр четырёхзначного числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

исходник мой неверен в чем моя ошибка?
Напишите программу для нахождения цифр четырёхзначного числа.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подаётся положительное четырёхзначное целое число.

Формат выходных данных
Программа должна вывести текст в соответствии с условием задачи.

Sample Input 1:

3281

Sample Output 1:

Цифра в позиции тысяч равна 3
Цифра в позиции сотен равна 2
Цифра в позиции десятков равна 8
Цифра в позиции единиц равна 1

```
a = int(input())
n1 = a //100000
n2 = a //1000
n3 = a //100
n4 = a % 3280
print('Цифра в позиции тысяч равна', n3)
print('Цифра в позиции сотен равна', n2)
print('Цифра в позиции десятков равна', n3)
print('Цифра в позиции единиц равна', n4)
```

Comment: ну тут в каждой строчке проблема

Comment: спасибо огромное)

Comment: ну так а что еще сказать? в n1 вы делите на 100000 тут будет всегда 0 т.к у вас 4ех значное число, в n2 вы получите первую цифру числа в n3 целую часть от деления на 100 это 38. про n4 даже смысла нет комментировать, откуда вы знаете на что делить если ввод происходит с клавиатуры?

Comment: ввод будет происходить не со стороны кого либо, тут инпут будет со стороны моего урока встроена я делил по разному что бы получить 3 2 8 1 по отдельности

Comment: У меня нет большого желания писать ответ так как задача довольно проста) Могу посоветовать изучить возможности преобразования данный в список, по типу list(str), а так же извлечение данных из списка по индексу - list[0], list[1] и т.д.

Comment: А зачем Вы ввод переводите в int, когда можно просто выдернуть цифры из строки по индексам?

Comment: ну так надо,так как я начинающий все идет пока по примитивными путями(((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не понятно зачем переводить в `int` строку ввода

```py
a = input()
print('Цифра в позиции тысяч равна', a[0])
print('Цифра в позиции сотен равна', a[1])
print('Цифра в позиции десятков равна', a[2])
print('Цифра в позиции единиц равна', a[3])
```

> это Вам для осмысления

```py
a = input()
print(
    *[
        f'Цифра в позиции {p} равна {v}' for p, v in zip(
            [
                'тысяч', 
                'сотен', 
                'десятков', 
                'единиц'
            ],
            a
        )
    ], sep='\n'
)
```

Comment: блин а че так можно было????? система приняла. столько я мучался((((

Comment: @Егор, не в обиду. Учите матчасть. Есть хороший тренинг сайт (как раз для тех, кто не особо любит гуглить) http://pythontutor.ru/

Comment: @Егор, чуть дополнил ответ

Answer (score 3):

/ - убрать число

% - оставить число

---

## Первый способ

1024 / 10 ( убрать 1 число справа ) = 102

102 % 10 ( оставить 1 число справа ) = 2

## Второй способ

1024 % 100 ( оставить 2 числа справа ) = 24

24 / 10 ( убрать 1 число справа ) = 2

2 / 10 ( убрать 1 число справа ) = 0

---

Это всё, что нужно знать для работы с цифрами числа.

Answer (score 2):

В python есть возможность из строки извлекать конкретный символ:

```
a=input("Введите число: ")
print('Цифра в позиции тысяч равна', a[1])
print('Цифра в позиции сотен равна', a[2])
print('Цифра в позиции десятков равна', a[3])
print('Цифра в позиции единиц равна', a[4])
```

Также хочу заметить, что эта функция a[i] принимает также и отрицательные значения, например:

```
a=1234
a[-1]=3 #2 символ с конца
a[0]=4  #1 символ с конца
```

И вообще ваши вычисления были не нужны, тем более они не верны. Если смотреть через числа то n1,n2,n3,n4 должны быть так вычислены:

```
a=int(a)
n1=a//1000
n2=(a//100)%10
n3=(a%100)//10
n4=a%10

print('Цифра в позиции тысяч равна', n1)
print('Цифра в позиции сотен равна', n2)
print('Цифра в позиции десятков равна', n3)
print('Цифра в позиции единиц равна', n4)
```

На всякий случай уточню, что знак "//" равносилен div, а "%" - mod.

Comment: Ну или через `divmod` можно. Вот так https://ideone.com/wmBVMn

Comment: @Namerek можно, но мне кажется новичку понятнее будет поотдельности div и mod

Comment: Наверное да. Но как сказал один из старожилов этого сайта `"Оказывается в python тоже можно программировать на C"`